problem with update archive.ubuntu
Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 13min 51s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

Check your system clock; you'll likely find it's ~2hrs+ out OR your timezone/locale details aren't matching your internet access point.

Does this answer your question? sudo apt update error: "Release file is not yet valid"

thank you very much .. its solved by changing time zone

thank you very much .. its solved by changing time zone
